# Sequences involving prime numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, pattern-recognition

> Start at $y=1$, then start observing sequences $a_{(x,y)}(n)$ for
>   $x=1,2,3,\dots$ and stop once you reach a sequence $a(n)$ that is
>   exactly the same as one of the previously observed sequences. This $x$
>   is the stopping point for this $y$.  Now move onto the next natural
>   number $y$, and repeat, considering all sequences so far, to find the
>   stopping point for that $y$.
>
> If the sequences are defined as the following:
>
> $$ a_{(x,y)}(n) = (n^x+1)\bmod y$$
>
> How to directly find the stopping $x$ for some $y$?

**Edit:** Examples of the process:

```
a_(1,1)= 0, 0,...
a_(2,1)= 0, 0,...
For y=1, we stop at x=2, since a(1,1)=a(2,1)

a_(1,2)= 1, 0, 1,...
a_(2,2)= 1, 0, 1,...
For y=2, we stop at x=2, since a(1,2)=a(2,2)

a_(1,3)= 1, 2, 0, 1,...
a_(2,3)= 1, 2, 2, 1,...
a_(3,3)= 1, 2, 0, 1,...
For y=3, we stop at x=3, since a(1,3)=a(3,3)

a_(1,4)= 1, 2, 3, 0, 1,...
a_(2,4)= 1, 2, 1, 2, 1,...
a_(3,4)= 1, 2, 1, 0, 1,...
a_(4,4)= 1, 2, 1, 2, 1,...
For y=4, we stop at x=4, since a(2,4)=a(4,4)

a_(1,5)= 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1,...
a_(2,5)= 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1,...
a_(3,5)= 1, 2, 4, 3, 0, 1,...
a_(4,5)= 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1,...
a_(5,5)= 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1,...
For y=5, we stop at x=5, since a(1,5)=a(5,5)

a_(1,6)= 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1,...
a_(2,6)= 1, 2, 5, 4, 5, 2, 1,...
a_(3,6)= 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1,...
For y=6, we stop at x=3, since a(1,6)=a(3,6)
```

I'm not familiar with modular arithmetic, so I tried to compute the results and observe if I can see any patterns among them.

I've observed that if $y$ is a prime number, then the stopping point is exactly $x=y$ .

I'm not sure how to find a general way to calculate/compute the stopping $x$ if $y$ is composite.

Here are the computed results: `y      x      [prime factorization of y]`

```
1        2       []
2        2       [2]
3        3       [3]
4        4       [2, 2]
5        5       [5]
6        3       [2, 3]
7        7       [7]
8        5       [2, 2, 2]
9        8       [3, 3]
10       5       [2, 5]
11       11      [11]
12       4       [2, 2, 3]
13       13      [13]
14       7       [2, 7]
15       5       [3, 5]
16       8       [2, 2, 2, 2]
17       17      [17]
18       8       [2, 3, 3]
19       19      [19]
20       6       [2, 2, 5]
21       7       [3, 7]
22       11      [2, 11]
23       23      [23]
24       5       [2, 2, 2, 3]
25       22      [5, 5]
26       13      [2, 13]
27       21      [3, 3, 3]
28       8       [2, 2, 7]
29       29      [29]
30       5       [2, 3, 5]
31       31      [31]
32       13      [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
33       11      [3, 11]
34       17      [2, 17]
35       13      [5, 7]
36       8       [2, 2, 3, 3]
37       37      [37]
38       19      [2, 19]
39       13      [3, 13]
40       7       [2, 2, 2, 5]
41       41      [41]
42       7       [2, 3, 7]
43       43      [43]
44       12      [2, 2, 11]
45       14      [3, 3, 5]
46       23      [2, 23]
47       47      [47]
48       8       [2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
49       44      [7, 7]
50       22      [2, 5, 5]
51       17      [3, 17]
52       14      [2, 2, 13]
53       53      [53]
54       21      [2, 3, 3, 3]
55       21      [5, 11]
56       9       [2, 2, 2, 7]
57       19      [3, 19]
58       29      [2, 29]
59       59      [59]
60       6       [2, 2, 3, 5]
61       61      [61]
62       31      [2, 31]
63       8       [3, 3, 7]
64       22      [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
65       13      [5, 13]
66       11      [2, 3, 11]
67       67      [67]
68       18      [2, 2, 17]
69       23      [3, 23]
70       13      [2, 5, 7]
71       71      [71]
72       9       [2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
73       73      [73]
74       37      [2, 37]
75       22      [3, 5, 5]
76       20      [2, 2, 19]
77       31      [7, 11]
78       13      [2, 3, 13]
79       79      [79]
80       8       [2, 2, 2, 2, 5]
81       58      [3, 3, 3, 3]
82       41      [2, 41]
83       83      [83]
84       8       [2, 2, 3, 7]
85       17      [5, 17]
86       43      [2, 43]
87       29      [3, 29]
88       13      [2, 2, 2, 11]
89       89      [89]
90       14      [2, 3, 3, 5]
91       13      [7, 13]
92       24      [2, 2, 23]
93       31      [3, 31]
94       47      [2, 47]
95       37      [5, 19]
96       13      [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
97       97      [97]
98       44      [2, 7, 7]
99       32      [3, 3, 11]
100      22      [2, 2, 5, 5]
101      101     [101]
102      17      [2, 3, 17]
103      103     [103]
104      15      [2, 2, 2, 13]
105      13      [3, 5, 7]
106      53      [2, 53]
107      107     [107]
108      21      [2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
109      109     [109]
110      21      [2, 5, 11]
111      37      [3, 37]
112      16      [2, 2, 2, 2, 7]
113      113     [113]
114      19      [2, 3, 19]
115      45      [5, 23]
116      30      [2, 2, 29]
117      14      [3, 3, 13]
118      59      [2, 59]
119      49      [7, 17]
120      7       [2, 2, 2, 3, 5]
121      112     [11, 11]
122      61      [2, 61]
123      41      [3, 41]
124      32      [2, 2, 31]
125      103     [5, 5, 5]
126      8       [2, 3, 3, 7]
127      127     [127]
128      39      [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
129      43      [3, 43]
130      13      [2, 5, 13]
131      131     [131]
132      12      [2, 2, 3, 11]
133      19      [7, 19]
134      67      [2, 67]
135      39      [3, 3, 3, 5]
136      19      [2, 2, 2, 17]
137      137     [137]
138      23      [2, 3, 23]
139      139     [139]
140      14      [2, 2, 5, 7]
141      47      [3, 47]
142      71      [2, 71]
143      61      [11, 13]
144      16      [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
145      29      [5, 29]
146      73      [2, 73]
147      44      [3, 7, 7]
148      38      [2, 2, 37]
149      149     [149]
150      22      [2, 3, 5, 5]
151      151     [151]
152      21      [2, 2, 2, 19]
153      50      [3, 3, 17]
154      31      [2, 7, 11]
155      61      [5, 31]
156      14      [2, 2, 3, 13]
157      157     [157]
158      79      [2, 79]
159      53      [3, 53]
160      13      [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5]
161      67      [7, 23]
162      58      [2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
163      163     [163]
164      42      [2, 2, 41]
165      21      [3, 5, 11]
166      83      [2, 83]
167      167     [167]
168      9       [2, 2, 2, 3, 7]
169      158     [13, 13]
170      17      [2, 5, 17]
171      20      [3, 3, 19]
172      44      [2, 2, 43]
173      173     [173]
174      29      [2, 3, 29]
175      62      [5, 5, 7]
176      24      [2, 2, 2, 2, 11]
177      59      [3, 59]
178      89      [2, 89]
179      179     [179]
180      14      [2, 2, 3, 3, 5]
181      181     [181]
182      13      [2, 7, 13]
183      61      [3, 61]
184      25      [2, 2, 2, 23]
185      37      [5, 37]
186      31      [2, 3, 31]
187      81      [11, 17]
188      48      [2, 2, 47]
189      21      [3, 3, 3, 7]
190      37      [2, 5, 19]
191      191     [191]
192      22      [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
193      193     [193]
194      97      [2, 97]
195      13      [3, 5, 13]
196      44      [2, 2, 7, 7]
197      197     [197]
198      32      [2, 3, 3, 11]
199      199     [199]
200      23      [2, 2, 2, 5, 5]
201      67      [3, 67]
202      101     [2, 101]
203      85      [7, 29]
204      18      [2, 2, 3, 17]
205      41      [5, 41]
206      103     [2, 103]
207      68      [3, 3, 23]
208      16      [2, 2, 2, 2, 13]
209      91      [11, 19]
210      13      [2, 3, 5, 7]
211      211     [211]
212      54      [2, 2, 53]
213      71      [3, 71]
214      107     [2, 107]
215      85      [5, 43]
216      21      [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
217      31      [7, 31]
218      109     [2, 109]
219      73      [3, 73]
220      22      [2, 2, 5, 11]
221      49      [13, 17]
222      37      [2, 3, 37]
223      223     [223]
224      29      [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 7]
225      62      [3, 3, 5, 5]
226      113     [2, 113]
227      227     [227]
228      20      [2, 2, 3, 19]
229      229     [229]
230      45      [2, 5, 23]
231      31      [3, 7, 11]
232      31      [2, 2, 2, 29]
233      233     [233]
234      14      [2, 3, 3, 13]
235      93      [5, 47]
236      60      [2, 2, 59]
237      79      [3, 79]
238      49      [2, 7, 17]
239      239     [239]
240      8       [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5]
241      241     [241]
242      112     [2, 11, 11]
243      167     [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
244      62      [2, 2, 61]
245      86      [5, 7, 7]
246      41      [2, 3, 41]
247      37      [13, 19]
248      33      [2, 2, 2, 31]
249      83      [3, 83]
250      103     [2, 5, 5, 5]
251      251     [251]
252      8   [2, 2, 3, 3, 7]
253      111     [11, 23]
254      127     [2, 127]
255      17      [3, 5, 17]
256      72      [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
257      257     [257]
258      43      [2, 3, 43]
259      37      [7, 37]
260      14      [2, 2, 5, 13]
261      86      [3, 3, 29]
262      131     [2, 131]
263      263     [263]
264      13      [2, 2, 2, 3, 11]
265      53      [5, 53]
266      19      [2, 7, 19]
267      89      [3, 89]
268      68      [2, 2, 67]
269      269     [269]
270      39      [2, 3, 3, 3, 5]
271      271     [271]
272      20      [2, 2, 2, 2, 17]
273      13      [3, 7, 13]
274      137     [2, 137]
275      22      [5, 5, 11]
276      24      [2, 2, 3, 23]
277      277     [277]
278      139     [2, 139]
279      32      [3, 3, 31]
280      15      [2, 2, 2, 5, 7]
281      281     [281]
282      47      [2, 3, 47]
283      283     [283]
284      72      [2, 2, 71]
285      37      [3, 5, 19]
286      61      [2, 11, 13]
287      121     [7, 41]
288      29      [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
289      274     [17, 17]
290      29      [2, 5, 29]
291      97      [3, 97]
292      74      [2, 2, 73]
293      293     [293]
294      44      [2, 3, 7, 7]
295      117     [5, 59]
296      39      [2, 2, 2, 37]
297      93      [3, 3, 3, 11]
298      149     [2, 149]
299      133     [13, 23]
300      22      [2, 2, 3, 5, 5]
301      43      [7, 43]
302      151     [2, 151]
303      101     [3, 101]
304      40      [2, 2, 2, 2, 19]
305      61      [5, 61]
306      50      [2, 3, 3, 17]
307      307     [307]
308      32      [2, 2, 7, 11]
309      103     [3, 103]
310      61      [2, 5, 31]
311      311     [311]
312      15      [2, 2, 2, 3, 13]
313      313     [313]
314      157     [2, 157]
315      14      [3, 3, 5, 7]
316      80      [2, 2, 79]
317      317     [317]
318      53      [2, 3, 53]
319      141     [11, 29]
320      22      [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5]
321      107     [3, 107]
322      67      [2, 7, 23]
323      145     [17, 19]
324      58      [2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
325      62      [5, 5, 13]
326      163     [2, 163]
327      109     [3, 109]
328      43      [2, 2, 2, 41]
329      139     [7, 47]
330      21      [2, 3, 5, 11]
331      331     [331]
332      84      [2, 2, 83]
333      38      [3, 3, 37]
334      167     [2, 167]
335      133     [5, 67]
336      16      [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 7]
337      337     [337]
338      158     [2, 13, 13]
339      113     [3, 113]
340      18      [2, 2, 5, 17]
341      31      [11, 31]
342      20      [2, 3, 3, 19]
343      297     [7, 7, 7]
344      45      [2, 2, 2, 43]
345      45      [3, 5, 23]
346      173     [2, 173]
347      347     [347]
348      30      [2, 2, 3, 29]
349      349     [349]
350      62      [2, 5, 5, 7]
351      39      [3, 3, 3, 13]
352      45      [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 11]
353      353     [353]
354      59      [2, 3, 59]
355      141     [5, 71]
356      90      [2, 2, 89]
357      49      [3, 7, 17]
358      179     [2, 179]
359      359     [359]
360      15      [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5]
361      344     [19, 19]
362      181     [2, 181]
363      112     [3, 11, 11]
364      14      [2, 2, 7, 13]
365      73      [5, 73]
366      61      [2, 3, 61]
367      367     [367]
368      48      [2, 2, 2, 2, 23]
369      122     [3, 3, 41]
370      37      [2, 5, 37]
371      157     [7, 53]
372      32      [2, 2, 3, 31]
373      373     [373]
374      81      [2, 11, 17]
375      103     [3, 5, 5, 5]
376      49      [2, 2, 2, 47]
377      85      [13, 29]
378      21      [2, 3, 3, 3, 7]
379      379     [379]
380      38      [2, 2, 5, 19]
381      127     [3, 127]
382      191     [2, 191]
383      383     [383]
384      39      [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
385      61      [5, 7, 11]
386      193     [2, 193]
387      44      [3, 3, 43]
388      98      [2, 2, 97]
389      389     [389]
390      13      [2, 3, 5, 13]
391      177     [17, 23]
392      45      [2, 2, 2, 7, 7]
393      131     [3, 131]
394      197     [2, 197]
395      157     [5, 79]
396      32      [2, 2, 3, 3, 11]
397      397     [397]
398      199     [2, 199]
399      19      [3, 7, 19]
400      24      [2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5]
401      401     [401]
402      67      [2, 3, 67]
403      61      [13, 31]
404      102     [2, 2, 101]
405      112     [3, 3, 3, 3, 5]
406      85      [2, 7, 29]
407      181     [11, 37]
408      19      [2, 2, 2, 3, 17]
409      409     [409]
410      41      [2, 5, 41]
411      137     [3, 137]
412      104     [2, 2, 103]
413      175     [7, 59]
414      68      [2, 3, 3, 23]
415      165     [5, 83]
416      29      [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 13]
417      139     [3, 139]
418      91      [2, 11, 19]
419      419     [419]
420      14      [2, 2, 3, 5, 7]
421      421     [421]
422      211     [2, 211]
423      140     [3, 3, 47]
424      55      [2, 2, 2, 53]
425      82      [5, 5, 17]
426      71      [2, 3, 71]
427      61      [7, 61]
428      108     [2, 2, 107]
429      61      [3, 11, 13]
430      85      [2, 5, 43]
431      431     [431]
432      40      [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
433      433     [433]
434      31      [2, 7, 31]
435      29      [3, 5, 29]
436      110     [2, 2, 109]
437      199     [19, 23]
438      73      [2, 3, 73]
439      439     [439]
440      23      [2, 2, 2, 5, 11]
441      44      [3, 3, 7, 7]
442      49      [2, 13, 17]
443      443     [443]
444      38      [2, 2, 3, 37]
445      89      [5, 89]
446      223     [2, 223]
447      149     [3, 149]
448      54      [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 7]
449      449     [449]
450      62      [2, 3, 3, 5, 5]
451      41      [11, 41]
452      114     [2, 2, 113]
453      151     [3, 151]
454      227     [2, 227]
455      13      [5, 7, 13]
456      21      [2, 2, 2, 3, 19]
457      457     [457]
458      229     [2, 229]
459      147     [3, 3, 3, 17]
460      46      [2, 2, 5, 23]
461      461     [461]
462      31      [2, 3, 7, 11]
463      463     [463]
464      32      [2, 2, 2, 2, 29]
465      61      [3, 5, 31]
466      233     [2, 233]
467      467     [467]
468      14      [2, 2, 3, 3, 13]
469      67      [7, 67]
470      93      [2, 5, 47]
471      157     [3, 157]
472      61      [2, 2, 2, 59]
473      211     [11, 43]
474      79      [2, 3, 79]
475      182     [5, 5, 19]
476      50      [2, 2, 7, 17]
477      158     [3, 3, 53]
478      239     [2, 239]
479      479     [479]
480      13      [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5]
481      37      [13, 37]
482      241     [2, 241]
483      67      [3, 7, 23]
484      112     [2, 2, 11, 11]
485      97      [5, 97]
486      167     [2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
487      487     [487]
488      63      [2, 2, 2, 61]
489      163     [3, 163]
490      86      [2, 5, 7, 7]
491      491     [491]
492      42      [2, 2, 3, 41]
493      113     [17, 29]
494      37      [2, 13, 19]
495      62      [3, 3, 5, 11]
496      64      [2, 2, 2, 2, 31]
497      211     [7, 71]
498      83      [2, 3, 83]
499      499     [499]
500      103     [2, 2, 5, 5, 5]
501      167     [3, 167]
502      251     [2, 251]
503      503     [503]
504      9       [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 7]
505      101     [5, 101]
506      111     [2, 11, 23]
507      158     [3, 13, 13]
508      128     [2, 2, 127]
509      509     [509]
510      17      [2, 3, 5, 17]
511      73      [7, 73]
512      137     [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
513      21      [3, 3, 3, 19]
514      257     [2, 257]
515      205     [5, 103]
516      44      [2, 2, 3, 43]
517      231     [11, 47]
518      37      [2, 7, 37]
519      173     [3, 173]
520      15      [2, 2, 2, 5, 13]
521      521     [521]
522      86      [2, 3, 3, 29]
523      523     [523]
524      132     [2, 2, 131]
525      62      [3, 5, 5, 7]
526      263     [2, 263]
527      241     [17, 31]
528      24      [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 11]
529      508     [23, 23]
530      53      [2, 5, 53]
531      176     [3, 3, 59]
532      20      [2, 2, 7, 19]
533      121     [13, 41]
534      89      [2, 3, 89]
535      213     [5, 107]
536      69      [2, 2, 2, 67]
537      179     [3, 179]
538      269     [2, 269]
539      212     [7, 7, 11]
540      39      [2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5]
541      541     [541]
542      271     [2, 271]
543      181     [3, 181]
544      21      [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 17]
545      109     [5, 109]
546      13      [2, 3, 7, 13]
547      547     [547]
548      138     [2, 2, 137]
549      62      [3, 3, 61]
550      22      [2, 5, 5, 11]
551      253     [19, 29]
552      25      [2, 2, 2, 3, 23]
553      79      [7, 79]
554      277     [2, 277]
555      37      [3, 5, 37]
556      140     [2, 2, 139]
557      557     [557]
558      32      [2, 3, 3, 31]
559      85      [13, 43]
560      16      [2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 7]
561      81      [3, 11, 17]
562      281     [2, 281]
563      563     [563]
564      48      [2, 2, 3, 47]
565      113     [5, 113]
566      283     [2, 283]
567      58      [3, 3, 3, 3, 7]
568      73      [2, 2, 2, 71]
569      569     [569]
570      37      [2, 3, 5, 19]
571      571     [571]
572      62      [2, 2, 11, 13]
573      191     [3, 191]
574      121     [2, 7, 41]
575      222     [5, 5, 23]
576      54      [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
577      577     [577]
578      274     [2, 17, 17]
579      193     [3, 193]
580      30      [2, 2, 5, 29]
581      247     [7, 83]
582      97      [2, 3, 97]
583      261     [11, 53]
584      75      [2, 2, 2, 73]
585      14      [3, 3, 5, 13]
586      293     [2, 293]
587      587     [587]
588      44      [2, 2, 3, 7, 7]
589      91      [19, 31]
590      117     [2, 5, 59]
591      197     [3, 197]
592      40      [2, 2, 2, 2, 37]
593      593     [593]
594      93      [2, 3, 3, 3, 11]
595      49      [5, 7, 17]
596      150     [2, 2, 149]
597      199     [3, 199]
598      133     [2, 13, 23]
599      599     [599]
600      23      [2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5]
601      601     [601]
602      43      [2, 7, 43]
603      68      [3, 3, 67]
604      152     [2, 2, 151]
605      222     [5, 11, 11]
606      101     [2, 3, 101]
607      607     [607]
608      77      [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 19]
609      85      [3, 7, 29]
610      61      [2, 5, 61]
611      277     [13, 47]
612      50      [2, 2, 3, 3, 17]
613      613     [613]
614      307     [2, 307]
615      41      [3, 5, 41]
616      33      [2, 2, 2, 7, 11]
617      617     [617]
618      103     [2, 3, 103]
619      619     [619]
620      62      [2, 2, 5, 31]
621      201     [3, 3, 3, 23]
622      311     [2, 311]
623      265     [7, 89]
624      16      [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 13]
625      504     [5, 5, 5, 5]
626      313     [2, 313]
627      91      [3, 11, 19]
628      158     [2, 2, 157]
629      145     [17, 37]
630      14      [2, 3, 3, 5, 7]
631      631     [631]
632      81      [2, 2, 2, 79]
633      211     [3, 211]
634      317     [2, 317]
635      253     [5, 127]
636      54      [2, 2, 3, 53]
637      86      [7, 7, 13]
638      141     [2, 11, 29]
639      212     [3, 3, 71]
640      39      [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5]
641      641     [641]
642      107     [2, 3, 107]
643      643     [643]
644      68      [2, 2, 7, 23]
645      85      [3, 5, 43]
646      145     [2, 17, 19]
647      647     [647]
648      58      [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
649      291     [11, 59]
650      62      [2, 5, 5, 13]
651      31      [3, 7, 31]
652      164     [2, 2, 163]
653      653     [653]
654      109     [2, 3, 109]
655      261     [5, 131]
656      44      [2, 2, 2, 2, 41]
657      74      [3, 3, 73]
658      139     [2, 7, 47]
659      659     [659]
660      22      [2, 2, 3, 5, 11]
661      661     [661]
662      331     [2, 331]
663      49      [3, 13, 17]
664      85      [2, 2, 2, 83]
665      37      [5, 7, 19]
666      38      [2, 3, 3, 37]
667      309     [23, 29]
668      168     [2, 2, 167]
669      223     [3, 223]
670      133     [2, 5, 67]
671      61      [11, 61]
672      29      [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 7]
673      673     [673]
674      337     [2, 337]
675      183     [3, 3, 3, 5, 5]
676      158     [2, 2, 13, 13]
677      677     [677]
678      113     [2, 3, 113]
679      97      [7, 97]
680      19      [2, 2, 2, 5, 17]
681      227     [3, 227]
682      31      [2, 11, 31]
683      683     [683]
684      20      [2, 2, 3, 3, 19]
685      137     [5, 137]
686      297     [2, 7, 7, 7]
687      229     [3, 229]
688      88      [2, 2, 2, 2, 43]
689      157     [13, 53]
690      45      [2, 3, 5, 23]
691      691     [691]
692      174     [2, 2, 173]
693      32      [3, 3, 7, 11]
694      347     [2, 347]
695      277     [5, 139]
696      31      [2, 2, 2, 3, 29]
697      81      [17, 41]
698      349     [2, 349]
699      233     [3, 233]
700      62      [2, 2, 5, 5, 7]
701      701     [701]
702      39      [2, 3, 3, 3, 13]
703      37      [19, 37]
704      86      [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 11]
705      93      [3, 5, 47]
706      353     [2, 353]
707      301     [7, 101]
708      60      [2, 2, 3, 59]
709      709     [709]
710      141     [2, 5, 71]
711      80      [3, 3, 79]
712      91      [2, 2, 2, 89]
713      331     [23, 31]
714      49      [2, 3, 7, 17]
715      61      [5, 11, 13]
716      180     [2, 2, 179]
717      239     [3, 239]
718      359     [2, 359]
719      719     [719]
720      16      [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5]
721      103     [7, 103]
722      344     [2, 19, 19]
723      241     [3, 241]
724      182     [2, 2, 181]
725      142     [5, 5, 29]
726      112     [2, 3, 11, 11]
727      727     [727]
728      15      [2, 2, 2, 7, 13]
729      492     [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
730      73      [2, 5, 73]
731      337     [17, 43]
732      62      [2, 2, 3, 61]
733      733     [733]
734      367     [2, 367]
735      86      [3, 5, 7, 7]
736      93      [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 23]
737      331     [11, 67]
738      122     [2, 3, 3, 41]
739      739     [739]
740      38      [2, 2, 5, 37]
741      37      [3, 13, 19]
742      157     [2, 7, 53]
743      743     [743]
744      33      [2, 2, 2, 3, 31]
745      149     [5, 149]
746      373     [2, 373]
747      248     [3, 3, 83]
748      82      [2, 2, 11, 17]
749      319     [7, 107]
750      103     [2, 3, 5, 5, 5]
751      751     [751]
752      96      [2, 2, 2, 2, 47]
753      251     [3, 251]
754      85      [2, 13, 29]
755      301     [5, 151]
756      21      [2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7]
757      757     [757]
758      379     [2, 379]
759      111     [3, 11, 23]
760      39      [2, 2, 2, 5, 19]
761      761     [761]
762      127     [2, 3, 127]
763      109     [7, 109]
764      192     [2, 2, 191]
765      50      [3, 3, 5, 17]
766      383     [2, 383]
767      349     [13, 59]
768      72      [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
769      769     [769]
770      61      [2, 5, 7, 11]
771      257     [3, 257]
772      194     [2, 2, 193]
773      773     [773]
774      44      [2, 3, 3, 43]
775      62      [5, 5, 31]
776      99      [2, 2, 2, 97]
777      37      [3, 7, 37]
```

I've also noticed if the composite number is of form $y=2p$ or $y=3p$, where $p$ is a prime number not equal to $2$ or $3$ respectively; Then the stopping point is exactly $x=p$ .

If we try to extend to the $y=5p$, this only holds if $p=4k+1,k\in\mathbb N$ .

 Otherwise, $y=5p$ will have the stopping point  equal to $2p-1$ .

How can we extend this to all composite numbers which are a multiple of two primes, and show why are these observations so far *correct*?

> Can we find a general pattern for all composite numbers?
>
> That is, given any $y$, directly find the stopping $x$.

Comment: this is somewhat hard to read. Perhaps an explicit, worked example would clarify.  For instance, are we to assume that $a_n(x,y)=a_{(x,y)}(n)$?  When you speak of a sequence...which of the three variables $x,y,n$ is the index variable and which are fixed?

Comment: @lulu $n$ is iterated to generate elements of sequence $(x,y)$. Observe sequences $(x,y)$ for a fixed $y$ and increasing $x$ until a sequence repeats. $(1,2)=(2,2)=0,1,0,1,0,1,\dots$ Thus $x=2$ is stopping point for $y=2$ .

Comment: Ok...well, if $y=p$, a prime, then $n^{p}\equiv n\pmod y$.  That's Fermat's little theorem.  So we see at once that your process halts at $x=p$.  (to see that it doesn't halt for smaller $x$ you will need to invoke the existence of a primitive root $\pmod p$).

Comment: In the first sentence you talk of a sequence being indexed as $a_n(x,y)$ and in the next you talk of a sequence being indexed $a_{(x,y)}(n)$.  Which is it.  Do you have an array of sequence $a_{(x,y)}$ so that a typical sequence would be $a_{(3,7)} = \{2,2,0,2...\}$ (the $n$term of $a_{(x,y)}$ being $n^3 +1 \mod 7$)?  Or do you have  sequence of arrays $a_n$ were a typical array would be $a_3 = [0,0,1,0,4,4....][0,0,1,2,0,4,3,2,1,0,10,10,10,10,.....][0,0,1,2,3,4,0,3,1,8,6,....]....$.

Comment: @fleablood I'm sorry for the confusion. I hope that the idea is clear after the last edit.

Comment: Okay, I see you mean $a_{(x,y)} = \{1^x + 1\mod y, 2^x + 1 \mod y, 3^2 + 1 \mod y$.  BUt you say when you "go through" the $x,y$ and you stop when you get a repeat.  In what order do you go through the x,y?  You say you stop at (4,4) because $a_{(4,4)} = a_{(2,4)}$ but why did you do $a_{(2,4)}$ before $a_{(4,4)}$ when would you have checked $a_{(6,3)}$?  Would that be before or after you checked $a_{(2,4)}$?

Comment: @fleablood You search for stopping points for $y=1,2,3...$ in increasing order. Although I believe each $y$ can be observed on its own without impacting other $y$'s stopping points.

Comment: The stopping point for a certain $y$ is just the smallest $x$ such that $$\exists 0<k<x : \forall n: n^x \equiv n^{k}  \mod y$$.

Comment: I am still not entirely clear, but I expect the answer is one greater than the [Carmichael Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html), $\lambda (y)$.  We note that $\lambda (p)=p-1=\lambda (2p)=\lambda (3p)$.  On the other hand $\lambda (5p)=lcm (4,p-1)$ which is $p-1$ precisely when $p=4k+1$. if $p=4k-1$ then $\lambda (5p)=2p-2$.

Comment: Formatting question:  I constantly imagine (incorrectly) that \lcm will compile in the same way that \gcd does, but it does not.  Is there an obvious alternative (that handles spacing and such properly)?

Comment: @lulu I use "\operatorname{lcm}"

Comment: @rogerl  Ah, thank you.  I will play with that.

Comment: @lulu Since we're asking formatting questions: is there a way to use a nonstandard prologue (for example, containing definitions like that) by default on every post I make?

Comment: Actually, you did clarify this in the edits quit thoroughly.  Thank you.  And BTW this is very interesting question!  Google Fermat's Little Theorem and Euler's theorem.  That should give you insight into your discoveries.  Basically $a_(x_0, y) = a_(x_1=x_0+k,y)$ if $n^{x_0} \equiv n^{x_1} = n^{x_0}*n^{x_1 - x_0=k} \mod y$ for *ALL* $n$.  FLT and ET tell you when $n^w \equiv 1 \mod y$ or when $n^v \equiv n \mod y$.

Comment: " I constantly imagine (incorrectly) that \lcm will compile in the same way that \gcd does"  You and me both!   \text{lcm }(1,2) will render $\text{lcm }(1,2)$ and I *saw* someone do something like \functionname{lcm} which might be even better if I could remember it.  BTW  a "\" follow by a blank space renders a space.  (So let's see how $\functionname{lcm}(1,2)$ comes out....)

Comment: Is there a practical difference between \operatorname and \text.  \text is much easier (for me) to remember but....

Comment: @rogerl  No idea, sorry!